# Magento module custom block working in product details page but not working in list and grid page?

Tags: php, xml, magento-1.7

In [magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) I am writing one module. In my module lets say I have `mymodule.xml` where I want to insert my own block after this block

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
      <block type="test/test" name="test" as="other" template="test/test.phtml" >
        <block type="test/test" name="test_info" as="test_info" template="test/testinfo.phtml" />
      </block>
    </reference>
  </catalog_product_view>
```

This one is working fine in `product details view page` but when I am trying to show the same block  in `product category view and list view` its not working at all.
  The product list category is like this where I am inserting my code from `mymodule.xml`

```
    <catalog_product_list>
    <reference name="product.info">
       <block type="test/test" name="test" as="other" template="test/test.phtml" >
        <block type="test/test" name="test_info" as="test_info" template="test/testinfo.phtml" />
      </block>
    </reference>
  </catalog_product_list>
```

When I am going to check the changes in list view I can't see any changes (after clearing cache). So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this issue. Any help and suggestions wll be really appreciable. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Well, The xml code which you are using in the category page ( list page) is not correct.
It should be like this :

```
<catalog_category_default>
<reference name="category.products">
    <block type="test/test" name="test" as="other" template="test/test.phtml" >
        <block type="test/test" name="test_info" as="test_info" template="test/testinfo.phtml" />
    </block>
</reference></catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
<reference name="category.products">
   <block type="test/test" name="test" as="other" template="test/test.phtml" >
    <block type="test/test" name="test_info" as="test_info" template="test/testinfo.phtml" />
  </block>
</reference>  </catalog_category_layered>
```

Please try with that. And, if anything else, please contact me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you call that child html like this? $this->getChildHtml('other');